# Error while running a Node js program

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js

I have written a node js program which contained a method called    `AWS.config.update()`. When I tried to run it on terminal, I got an error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'

Comment: I would add the 'aws-sdk' tag

Answer (score 11):

Go to the folder where your node application is installed:

`cd location/to/your/folder`

And then run this to install the aws-sdk:

`npm install aws-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

After `npm install aws-sdk` be sure that your package.json specifies the exact version of the new dependency, such as:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "2.4.12",
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk to see various ways to install `aws-sdk`.

I prefer always adding dependency on `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.182.0"
}
```

and run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve same thing and got same error

I had installed `aws-sdk` globally using `npm i -g aws-sdk`
 Note running the node file from command line `const AWS = require('aws-sdk')` would not work, if there is no local `node_modules` folder which contains `aws-sdk`
**Solution only for MAC**
 `const AWS = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-sdk');`
For other OS, find the location of globally installed node_modules